# Htaccess to convert 'GET' to slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have the page '/tags.php?id=foo', and want it to display in the browser as '/tags/foo'. How might I do this with the .htaccess file?

**EDIT**
I've tried the solution given below and read up a little bit on Regex, but it's still not quite working how I need it to - is it possible once using the .htaccess mod_rewrite to still derive the $_GET data from the URL to use in code?

Comment: Do you even search bro?

Comment: Yes, considering I've never done any regex before though none of the answers made any sense.

Comment: Well learn about regex in that case. You are expected to at least have a minimal understanding to participate on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/?$ /tags.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Note that this expects the _incoming_ URI to have SEO-format /, and converts to the dynamic URI format with `.php?id=`. It is _your_ responsibility elsewhere on your site to generate the SEO format addresses in your links.

Comment: Yes that is correct. If requirement is to redirect `/tags.php?id=foo` => `/tags/foo` then let me know and I will provide one more rule for that.

Comment: There is no point in converting an _incoming_ dynamic URI (`.php?id=`) to static (SEO), as you're just going to have to convert it immediately to something that the server and PHP can understand (the dynamic format).